# Remove characters before '-' and after '-' keeping the middle of the string that contain more one character '-'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I got the following entry in my database (varchar data type):

```
 5-359-258756-54
 2-456-58994-85
 4-458 -478698-42
 5-876-5878-26
```

I want to exclude first number plus char '-', last two numbers plus previous '-' and remove the spaces when available in the middle char ' -'.

The final result must be:

```
 359-258756
 456-58994
 458-478698
 876-5878
```

I tried to use mainly charindex & patindex with replace ' ',''  based in forum suggestions, but not show the expected result, the most close that I could return was 458-478698-42 (removing the first number plus character and the space),

How can I solve it?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.15996.0

Comment: Is it a result of `SELECT @@VERSION;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you string format is consistent, then you an use `parsename()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('5-359-258756-54')
,('2-456-58994-85')
,('4-458 -478698-42')
,('5-876-5878-26')

Select *
      ,NewVal = replace(parsename(replace(SomeCol,'-','.'),3)
                        +'-'
                        +parsename(replace(SomeCol,'-','.'),2)
                       ,' ','')
 From  @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol             NewVal
5-359-258756-54     359-258756
2-456-58994-85      456-58994
4-458 -478698-42    458-478698
5-876-5878-26       876-5878
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot John. By the way I didn't know the parsename() function in SQL, that is a new learning for me, thank you very much!

Comment: @ito Always happy to help.  Actually parsename() was introduced in v2008.

Comment: @ito Keep in mind that parsename() can only handle 4 elements.  1-4 is right to left.

Comment: And that `ParseName` fails _hard_ when the input isn't valid for an object name, e.g. `select ParseName( N'D.C.B.A.Oops', 3 );` returns `NULL`.